# Cocos2d-x проблемы с компиляцией

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d

Использую NDK R9d, C++, cocos2dx 3.8.1. Test cpp собирает без ошибок, прошлые проекты так же, но вот с новым есть проблемы

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
               ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
               ../../Classes/EnemyStackLayer.cpp \
               ../../Classes/GameOverScene.cpp \
               ../../Classes/GameScene.cpp \
               ../../Classes/LetClass.cpp \
               ../../Classes/MainMenuScene.cpp \
               ../../Classes/MyChar.cpp \
               ../../Classes/MyHUDLayer.cpp \
               ../../Classes/PauseScene.cpp
```

Если не убрать этот участок кода, компиляция не успешна:

```
    LetClass* LetClass::CreateLet(EnemyStackLayer* _gameplayLayer)
{
    LetClass* ob = new LetClass();

    if (ob && ob->initEnemy(_gameplayLayer))
    {
        ob->autorelease();  

        ob->_addEvents();

        return ob;
    }

    CC_SAFE_DELETE(ob);
    return NULL;

}
```

Инициализация

```
bool LetClass::initEnemy(EnemyStackLayer* _gameplayLayer)
{
    cocos2d::CCSize visibleSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleSize();
    gameplayLayer = _gameplayLayer;

    Health = 2.0;
    DamageToHero = 1.0;
    primaryHP = 2.0;


    Speed = gameplayLayer->NewS;

    int min = 95;
    int max = visibleSize.width - 95;

    int rnd = (CCRANDOM_0_1() * (max - min)) + min;
    playerSprite = Sprite::create("GameScreen/Asteroid_0.png");
    cocos2d::Point p = cocos2d::Point(rnd, -5);
    playerSprite->setPosition(p);

    addChild(playerSprite, -1);


    return true;
}
```

Заголовок:

```
class LetClass : public cocos2d::Sprite
{
public: 
    EnemyStackLayer* gameplayLayer;

    static LetClass* CreateLet(EnemyStackLayer* _gameplayLayer);
    bool initEnemy(EnemyStackLayer* _gameplayLayer);

    cocos2d::Sprite *playerSprite;
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена
Нужно было поменять функции местами.